# Python Selenium: using wildcard in SQL

Tags: python, sql, selenium, automation, wildcard

I am trying different ways to work out on **Wildcard** in Python for my **SQL** Query, Could anyone please help me in my syntax:
I need Query like ,

```
    SELECT Title from Task where Title like '%abc%' -- SQL
```

to be written in Python

**TRY 1:**

```
sql = '''
       (""" SELECT TITLE FROM TASK 
        WHERE TITLE LIKE %s""", ('%' +?+ '%',))
       '''
cursor.execute(sql, id)
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

**TRY 2:**

```
sql = '''
       (""" SELECT TITLE FROM TASK 
        WHERE TITLE LIKE '%%%?%%'
       '''
cursor.execute(sql, id)
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

ANy help on my syntax please.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work

```
sql = '''
       (""" SELECT TITLE FROM TASK 
        WHERE TITLE LIKE '{}'
       '''
sql.format(id)
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
wildcard = 'example'

sql = f"""
       SELECT TITLE FROM TASK 
       WHERE TITLE LIKE '{wildcard}'
       """
       
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchone()
```

This should simply replace the {wildcard} with whatever you decide in the wildcard = "?" part.

Comment: you mean like, SELECT TITLE FROM  TASK
            WHERE TITLE LIKE '{?}'

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it like this :

```
wildcar_str = '%abc%'
sql = "SELECT TITLE FROM TASK WHERE TITLE LIKE '%s' " %wildcar_str
```